# Complete ajax, then start again

Tags: php, ajax, chat, call, abort

I'm working on a php-ajax chat, and I use two main methods: "update" and "send"

Update function (ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 9999999999999999,
    url: 'process.php',
    success: ...
});
```

Process.php:

```
function update(){
   if(new messages){
   echo new messages...
   }else{
   sleep(5);update(); again...
   }
}
```

Send function (ajax):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "send.php",
success: function(){
update();}
})
```

I want to stop running "update" request when sending new message and start it again immediently, so sender will instantly see his message. I have tried ajax.abort() but it can still continue to execute the call on server side.

How can I complete the ajax call and make return success, not aborting it?

Comment: You should look into web sockets. Hanging requests are passe.

Comment: web sockets support is limited, so only usefull if you have control over the browsers that use the application (internal)

Comment: @HugoDelsing ... or if you don't mind offering reduced experience to IE<10 users. Of course, if you have the time and patience to write a websocket solution + hanging requests fallback... ;-)

Comment: Note that most proxies will cut a request hanging _this_ long.

Comment: @Jan I can lower timeout to 60 sec and start it again on "timeout" error, it's not principal

Comment: It's always a good idea to try to avoid using `sleep()` even for short periods of time. Using `sleep()` will open your server to a very, _very_ easy DoS attack.

Comment: @Adnan the alternative would be active waiting (which is even worse) or not using long requests (which needs websockets or polling).

Comment: keep in mind that on some ie9 installations the timeout is set wrongfully and timeout is only 10seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code you could check for connection aborted
http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

But if you realy want to return "success" I would add something to the session in send.php like

```
$_SESSION['SENDNOW']=true;
```

and then in the Process.php I would check for

```
if(new messages || $_SESSION['SENDNOW']==true){
   $_SESSION['SENDNOW']=false;
}
```

perhaps you should make the timeout 1sec for quicker response times. Or if you do it perfectly you could check quickly (like every 500ms) for $_SESSION['SENDNOW']==true and only every 5seconds for new messages

Comment: 5 sec is an example, I use 1 sec, but it still makes a difference, but 0.5 sec will load cpu twice more. I like your method with $_SESSION

Comment: you could alter your update function to be processed every 500ms. Then on every attempt you check the session and only every other attempt you check for new messages

Comment: we can ckeck for $_SESSION['SENDNOW'] only after sleep(), my goal is to stop the call even through sleep()

Comment: during sleep you cannot do anything. Thats why i advised to keep sleep time to a minimum to allow faster updates

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

First document.ready() function declares an Ajax call as variable like below:

```
var ajaxCall = null;
```

Put this code in within your AJAX function at top:

```
//AJAX request aborted
if ( typeof ajaxCall != 'undefined' ) {
     return false;
}
```

For call to AJAX like this:

```
ajaxCall = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 9999999999999999,
    url: 'process.php',
    success: ...
});
```

So every time not call to server.